# Upper bound on the probability of the maximum of random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider the random variables $X_{i}$, i=1,2,..,N defined on some probability space with $sup_{i}E|X_{i}|<\infty$. Nothing else is known about the $X_{i}'s$.

Is there any upper bound on $P(\max_{i}|X_{i}|$>c) available expressed in terms of $\max_{i}E|X_{i}|$?

Comment: Better than the union bound, $P(\max |X_i|>c)\le N \max E|X_i| / c? $

Comment: "Nothing else is known" > so you don't assume independence either?

Comment: Independence could be assumed.